# Internal card reader fails after upgrade to Windows 10 - "Device could not be migrated"

Tags: usb, windows-10, card-reader

I have just upgraded from Windows 7 to Windows 10, everything went smoothly except for one thing: My internal card reader mostly stopped working - it doesn't recognize any card that I can insert into it (although the card reader's USB port still works).

The reader and its slots are recognized by the Device manager (there are a couple of "Generic STORAGE DEVICE USB Device"s), and if I look at their Properties, Windows tells me that the device is working. However, if I look at the "Events" page, there are three entries (translated from German):

```
06.08.2015 13:56:51   Device not migrated
06.08.2015 13:56:51   Device configured (disk.inf)
06.08.2015 13:56:51   Device started (disk)
```

and the comments for the "not migrated" message say (translated):

```
The device "USBSTOR\Disk&Ven_Generic&Prod_STORAGE_DEVICE&Rev_9744\000000009744&0" 
could not be migrated.

ID of the last device instance: USBSTOR\DISK&VEN_GENERIC&PROD_AUDIO___PRODUCT&REV_V2.0\01234567890C&0
Class GUID: {4D36E967-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}
Location Path: 
Migration Rank: 0xF000EC001001F120
Present: false
Status: 0xC0000719
```

I tried it with a different device (Revoltec Procyon 1.5), same result. I also tried an external USB card reader - the reader itself is recognized, but its ports show the same behavior.

My motherboard is a [Gigabyte GA-P55_USB3 (rev. 1)](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=3440#ov).

Any ideas what I can do?

Comment: I assume you have attempted to delete the device, when prompted deleted the driver, then used device manager to detect the device again after a reboot?  Information about the card reader might be helpful.

Comment: @Ramhound: I removed the device and replaced it with a different device by a different manufacturer (which was then detected for the very first time on the next boot), so I guess that's somewhat equivalent?

Comment: I suppose it is.  I was just indicating remove it from device manager, when prompted delete the driver, then reboot and when prompted install the driver.

Comment: Did you tried to install Gigabyte GA-P55_USB3 chipset driver for your Windows 10 version downloaded from Gigabyte's website? Don't assume Windows Update should get the correct driver...

Comment: It is just a USB device. edumgui is correct. Update your chipset and USB controller drivers. Maybe plug in to a different slot. I think the fact that you can't get any card reader to work might be a clue. Is there a problem with the SD card you are trying to read?

Comment: Use disk management while plugging in the SD card:
https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-open-disk-management-2626080

Comment: It's not really a solution, but I tried accessing an SD a few weeks ago and it worked - so one of the Windows updates since 2015 must have fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Windows 10 upgrade can fail in unpredictable ways.

One way which might fix the problem is to ... do Windows 10 upgrade,
but this time not letting the upgrade download only the pieces that it thinks
it needs, but download the full installation and then upgrade Windows 10
to itself.

You will need to [Download a recent Windows 10 ISO File](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/9230-windows-10-iso-download.html) and use it for the
upgrade. The process is described in this article :

[Repair Install Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html)

This procedure is painfully slow and the download file is large,
but sometimes this helps in similar situations.
I cannot guarantee that it will help in your case.